# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not wait for the specified waitFor(long,timeunits) period

Tags: java, multithreading, file, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have a method that calls `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. The problem is that the command I'm trying to execute takes around 5 minutes to complete. That is perfectl normal. But the problem is `that waitFor(long,TimeUnit)` does not wait until those 5 minutes are done before returning.

For information : in shell mode, my custom jar take one argument : a file path and it processes that file. The command works perfectly in shell mode

Here is the code

```
private boolean processData(String pathToMyJar, String pathToMyFile){
    boolean result = false;
    try
            {            
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + pathToMyJar + "  " + pathToMyFile);                 
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream() ;
            InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<ERROR>");
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            while ( (line = br2.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</ERROR>");
            boolean exitVal = proc.waitFor(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
            } catch (Throwable t)
              {
                t.printStackTrace();
              }
return result;
}
```

As a result, my method ALWAYS return true

The standard output is always :

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
> -Dswing.aatext=true  Process exitValue: true

Would you help me figure solve this issue ?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments, I added stdout to read the output of may jar. What happens is that SSH sessions is not maintained. The jar establishes a successul SSH connection and then disconnects right away.
In shell mode that issue does not occur but with Runtime.exec(), it does

Below a little log including stdout

> Obtaining session connection --> user@192.168.1.2:22 Connection
> established.   Connection Type is: SSH Finished Assessment 2/2
> Disconnecting Session... Exit Code 0  Process exitValue: true

Comment: Is it possible your JAR is writing a failure message to standard output and exiting, e.g. because it couldn't find the file you're trying to process?  (You are reading the process's `stderr` but not its `stdout`.)  Do either `pathToMyJar` or `pathToMyFile` have spaces in them?  Have you tried using a `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward. That was a good question. Stdout showed me what's happening. The jar starts a SSH remote session and is suppose to do its job. In shell mode, it lasts 5 minute. But in Runtime.exec(), it establishes the session and the right away disconnects. Therefore exit status is obviously 0. Needless to say I have no idea how this could be solved. Runtime.exec() does not allow SSH session to persist until processing is done.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you figure out what the problem with that JAR is, without more details of what it does other than establishing an SSH connection.  I simply don't know what could cause it to behave differently when called from the Java rather than the shell.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I understand the problem. For some reason, the jar is triggering 2 SSH connections before it starts its processing. In shell mode that is fine. But in java runtime.exec, the first exit is considered the end of the process therefore the 2nd SSH connection is never reached. I'll ask another question for that

Comment: @LukeWoodward I found the issue. First I changed to use Apache Commons-exec. It's better imho. Secons=d, all I needed to do was to set the working directory. I get the JAR is using relative paths in its code. It's all fixed